# How can I create a button click handler?

Tags: c#, matlab, button, click, handler

I have a number of buttons which flicker at different frequencies in my Wondows Form Application. When a specific frequency is measured on the head by an electrode, the signal undergoes signalprocessing in MATLAB, hereafter the frequency found are sent to the application, where the specific value from the UDP connection should press the button which have this specific flickering frequency. I am a bit lost how to create this button handler, using the data I get from Matlab. My thought is:

Value from connection ->

```
if value == 6
{
    button1 is clicked
}
elseif value == 6.5
{
    button2 is clicked
}
```

and so forth.

Any ideas any one ?

---

```
 if(returnData == String.Empty)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            button2.PerformClick();
        }
```

Here the returnData is the ongiong incomming data from the UDP connection to MATLAB, you this would work ?

And for another question, I am having a bit of trouble with UDP connection, I would like if it could receive the data I am sending, right now, I have to press a button to open and recieve data, I have made it like this, because I could not update the data otherwise. In mind, I am a novice to C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //public UdpClient receivingUdpClient = null;
        public string returnData;
        //public byte[] Receive(ref IPEndPoint remoteEP);
       // private Print print = null;
                    //while (true)
            //{
            public UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(8051);
            //bool done = false;
            //Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP Address and port number of the sender.  
            // The IPEndPoint will allow you to read datagrams sent from any source.
            //while (true)
            //{
            public IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8051);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        label1.Visible = false;
        label2.Visible = false;


    }
    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Visible = false;
        try
        {
            //while (true)
            //{
            // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
            Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

            returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " +
                                        returnData.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                        RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                                        " on their port number " +
                                        RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());
            // }      
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
        }

        if(returnData == String.Empty)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            button2.PerformClick();
        }
    }

    void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SPELL.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + returnData;
            label1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SPELL.Text = null;
            SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + returnData;
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

}
```

This is my small test program in VIsual Studio so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about normal button you want to trigger the click event or you are talking about a ToggleButtons that you want to toggle on/off ?

Comment: Are you searching for [Button.PerformClick()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: That's the guess i am having, in witch case he better create an action list like `List<Tuple<double,Action>>` and search the list for the equivalent double and if exist execute the action that is already linked properly

Comment: Handler is something that gets called after the button is clicked. Do you want to simulate a button click so that you visually see the click "flickering" on the screen? or simply call the button handler?

Comment: I am talking about a normal button, whcih opens a new from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a button click from code behind, you could simply call the button's handler wherever you want the call to be made.

E.g.

```
 if (value == 6)
 {
  this.button1_click(this,new EventArgs()) //button1 is clicked
 }
 else if (value == 6.5)
 {
   this.button2_click(this,new EventArgs()) //button2 is clicked
 }
```

I'd recommend you better move the button handler's logic to a separate method and call the method instead of calling the handler directly.